# Python MongoDB : 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Just started with mongo db .

```
context = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    context['name']  = request.POST['name']
    context['username']  = request.POST['username']
    context['mobile']  = request.POST['mobile']
    get = db.messages.find( { 'name' : request.POST['name'] } )
    if get is not None:
        print get.name
```

I have two records in my database .

```
> db.messages.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513f2cf1ae4cb53c1374b4f6"), "username" : "hello@gmail.com", "mobile" : "78978555", "name" : "rohit" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513f2cfeae4cb53c1374b4f7"), "username" : "hi@gmail.com", "mobile" : "8528522", "name" : "Rohti" }
```

when i am posting the form with name rohit . I am getting the above error .

Please tell me what might i am doing wrong here .

I know i am doing wrong query in mongo db .Please help me to get back on track .

Comment: what is get when you print it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

get returns as a cursor in pymongo.

try:

```
for record in get:
    print record['name']
```

Also, get is not a good name for a variable.

Comment: thanks it is working for me   .But what if i want to check only for single record. Should i do the same for FindOne also ?

Comment: find_one returns a dict, so then you don't have to iterate but can directly address it: `x = find_one({'name': your_name})` then `print x['name']`

Comment: last thing what if there is no matching query it returns None or what?

Comment: try it. find will return an empty iterator. find_one will return None

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate with the cursor:

```
for element in get:
    print(element.name)
```

now you are accessing the cursor, which is just a generator of elements and doesn't contain the name directly. See [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/tutorial.html%5d) for a complete explanation.

Comment: Above query will also work  print(element.name) instead of  print(get.name)