# How to return Cursor value in Python with MongoDB to another calling function

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB collection and return fetched data to calling function. Code is as follows.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
db = client["DBName"]

def check(request):
    data = getData(2500, "2023-03-20")
    print(data)
    for d in data:
        print()
        print(d)
    return render(request, 'backtest.html')

def getData(value, somedate):
    collection = db[constantsCollection.NameData]
    query = {"$and": [{"value" : value}, {"datetime" : {"$regex" : somedate}}]}
    data = collection.find(query)
    return data
```

This code is giving error as *AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'get'*

Cursor is holding approx 10000 records.

I saw couple of answers but all are printing value in same function which works fine. (eg. [Python MongoDB : 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363444/python-mongodb-cursor-object-has-no-attribute-name))
Looking for how to return value to calling function.

Thanks for help in advance.

Traceback :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\user\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 56, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\user\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py",
> line 138, in **call**
> response = self.process_response(request, response)   File "C:\Users\user\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py",
> line 27, in process_response
> if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None: AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown that'd try to use a thing called `.get()`. Then again, you're not showing `getocdatafrommongo`.

Comment: You will also need to show the full traceback associated with the error, not just the error it's "giving".

Comment: Updated function name in code and added traceback

Comment: If that really is your traceback, then you're somehow returning the MongoDB cursor as a response, but that's also not what happens in the code you've posted. There's something off here that you're not showing us.